# Why this Selection Sort code not giving correct output?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

When I run the code I got result `7215` which is obviously not correct. The code is fine there is no error in terminal only the output is wrong. Please help I know this is a basic sorting algorithm but I am new to programming.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void sort(int arr[],int n);
int main()
{
   int a[]={2,7,1,5};
   sort(a,4);
   return 0;
}

void sort(int arr[],int n)
{
   int i,j,temp;
   int imin;
   for(int i=0;i<(n-2);i++)
   {
      imin=i;
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
         if(arr[j]<arr[imin])
         {
            imin=j;
         }
      }
      temp=arr[i];
      arr[i]=arr[imin];
      arr[imin]=temp;
   }
   int k;
   for(k=0;k<n;k++)
   {
      printf("\n%d\n",arr[k]);
   }
}
```

Comment: How can the code be fine and wrong at the same time?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: I guess it is "fine" in the sense that it compiles and runs without crashing. <g>

Answer (score 3):

Two errors here:

```
for(int i=0;i<(n-2);i++)
```

Why `-2`? You miss to compare the last elements this way, should be `-1`. The parantheses are unnecessary, but add some spaces instead to make it readable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
```

Then, the next loop is wrong as well:

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
```

By starting at 0 again, you compare with what you **already sorted** and destroy it. Change it to this:

```
for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
```

---

For problems like this, you should really read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). The rubber duck would have helped you.

Comment: thnx sir I got what u said.Now code is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You have made some silly mistakes, the selection sort algorithm works like this::

The selection sort algorithm sorts an array by repeatedly finding the minimum element (considering ascending order) from unsorted part and putting it at the beginning. The algorithm maintains two subarrays in a given array.

1) The subarray which is already sorted.
2) Remaining subarray which is unsorted.

In every iteration of selection sort, the minimum element (considering ascending order) from the unsorted subarray is picked and moved to the sorted subarray.

arr[] = 64 25 12 22 11

// Find the minimum element in arr[0...4]
// and place it at beginning
11 25 12 22 64

// Find the minimum element in arr[1...4]
// and place it at beginning of arr[1...4]
11 12 25 22 64

// Find the minimum element in arr[2...4]
// and place it at beginning of arr[2...4]
11 12 22 25 64

// Find the minimum element in arr[3...4]
// and place it at beginning of arr[3...4]
11 12 22 25 64

So your code should be like this:::

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void sort(int arr[],int n);
int main()
{
   int a[]={2,7,1,5};
   sort(a,4);
   return 0;
}

void sort(int arr[],int n)
{
   int i,j,temp;
   int imin;
   for(int i=0;i<(n-1);i++)
   {
      imin=i;
      for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
      {
         if(arr[j]<arr[imin])
         {
            imin=j;
         }
      }
      temp=arr[i];
      arr[i]=arr[imin];
      arr[imin]=temp;

   }
   int k;
   for(k=0;k<n;k++)
   {
      printf("\n%d\n",arr[k]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Way to many work there, keep it [simple](http://ideone.com/rTgArL).

Comment: Well, not sure whether explaining the algorithm was *necessary*, but maybe it helps someone. Still, you should fix the formatting of your answer to make it more readable.